# jQuery - count price from multiple dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem, and still don't know how to figure it out. 
I have a few dropdowns with price at the left side and next to each of them quantity. 
For example - left dropdown is like a size of photo and right is quantity.

I can't figure out how to count each pair of dropdowns and count a total price, only last pair creates total price, despite others.

```
function countPrice(){
    var total_price = 0.00;
    var data_price = "";
  var data_count = "";

  $(".tp-sel > option:selected").each(function(){
    data_price = parseFloat($(this).data("price")) || 0;
  });

  $(".tp-sel-count > option:selected").each(function(){
        data_count = parseFloat($(this).data("count")) || 0;
  });

  total_price = data_price * data_count;
  $("#price").html(total_price.toFixed(2));
  console.log("Price: " + data_price + "Count:" +data_count);
}
```

Here's fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cheslavcc/e1wqbqrL/4/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you iterate over the `divs` containing the `selects`, so that you can process each price and count as a pair. I've added a class to those container `div`s to make the iteration easier:

```js
function countPrice(){
  var total_price = 0.00;
  var data_price = "";
  var data_count = "";

  $(".product").each(function(){
    data_price = parseFloat($(this).find(".tp-sel > option:selected").data("price")) || 0;
    data_count = parseFloat($(this).find(".tp-sel-count > option:selected").data("count")) || 0;
    console.log("Price: " + data_price + "Count:" +data_count);
    total_price += data_price * data_count;
  })
  $("#price").html(total_price.toFixed(2));
}


$("#countprice").click(function(){
  countPrice();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 30%; display:block;" class="product">
  <select class="tp-sel">
    <option data-price="0.10">0.10</option>
    <option data-price="0.30">0.30</option>
    <option data-price="0.40">0.40</option>
  </select>
  <select class="tp-sel-count">
    <option data-count="1">1</option>
    <option data-count="2">2</option>
    <option data-count="3">3</option>
    <option data-count="4">4</option>    
  </select>
</div>
<div style="width: 30%; display:block;" class="product">
  <select class="tp-sel">
    <option data-price="0.10">0.10</option>
    <option data-price="0.30">0.30</option>
    <option data-price="0.40">0.40</option>
  </select>
  <select class="tp-sel-count">
    <option data-count="1">1</option>
    <option data-count="2">2</option>
    <option data-count="3">3</option>
    <option data-count="4">4</option>    
  </select>
</div>

<div style="width: 30%; display:block;" class="product">
  <select class="tp-sel">
    <option data-price="0.10">0.10</option>
    <option data-price="0.30">0.30</option>
    <option data-price="0.40">0.40</option>
  </select>
  <select class="tp-sel-count">
    <option data-count="1">1</option>
    <option data-count="2">2</option>
    <option data-count="3">3</option>
    <option data-count="4">4</option>    
  </select>
</div>
<div>
<span id="price">0.00</span>
<button id="countprice">
Count
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was easy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to process each pair, then what to do with the total?
In my example I simply put ALL the total price together...up to you to determine if that works. (this is really count ALL the prices - total)

```
function countPrice() {
  var total_price = 0.00;
  var data_price = "";
  var data_count = "";
  $(".tp-sel").each(function() {
    var oSel = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var pair_price = oSel.length ? parseFloat(oSel.data("price")) : 0;
    var oQty = $(this).next(".tp-sel-count").find('option:selected');
    var pair_count = oQty.length ? parseFloat(oQty.data("count")) : 0;
    var totalPair_price = pair_price * pair_count; // of this pair
    console.log("Price: " + pair_price + "Count:" + pair_count,totalPair_price);
    total_price += totalPair_price;
  });
  $("#price").html(total_price.toFixed(2));
}
```

Now if you want to do this on a change for an individual pair you can do something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.tp-sel', function() {
  var index = $(this).index('.tp-sel');
  console.log(index);
  var oSel = $(this).find('option:selected');
  var pair_price = oSel.length ? parseFloat(oSel.data("price")) : 0;
  var oQty = $(this).next(".tp-sel-count").find('option:selected');
  var pair_count = oQty.length ? parseFloat(oQty.data("count")) : 0;
  var totalPair_price = pair_price * pair_count; // of this pair
  console.log("Price: " + pair_price + "Count:" + pair_count, totalPair_price);
  $("#price").html(totalPair_price.toFixed(2));
});
```

To do that last on change of either dropdown pair:

```
$(document).on('change', '.tp-sel', function() {
  var index = $(this).index('.tp-sel');
  console.log(index);
  calcThis(index);
});
$(document).on('change', '.tp-sel-count', function() {
  var index = $(this).index('.tp-sel-count');
  console.log(index);
  calcThis(index);
});

function calcThis(index) {
  var sel = $('.tp-sel').eq(index);
  console.log(index);
  var oSel = sel.find('option:selected');
  var pair_price = oSel.length ? parseFloat(oSel.data("price")) : 0;
  var oQty = sel.next(".tp-sel-count").find('option:selected');
  var pair_count = oQty.length ? parseFloat(oQty.data("count")) : 0;
  var totalPair_price = pair_price * pair_count; // of this pair
  console.log("Price: " + pair_price + "Count:" + pair_count, totalPair_price);
  $("#price").html(totalPair_price.toFixed(2));
}
```